# replace textbox with datepicker using javascript when user selects date on dropdownbox

Tags: javascript

```html
<div>

<label for="searchby">Search By: </label>
    <select id="searchby"  name="search_by">
        <option value="date">Date</option>
        <option value="type">Type</option>
    </select>
<label for="searchcontent">Search value:</label>
<input id="searchcontent" type="text" name="search_data">
<input type="submit" value="search">

</div>
```

This image shows search by and searches data label. So, when user select date, search value textbox should be changed with datepicker which is not happening with me

[image]

Comment: Stackoverflow Community is not here to write code for you.The community is all about to resolve your problem.Please go through document https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: sorry, i don't mean it, i don't need code. I just need idea how to do that

Comment: Please find my snippet below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
    $('#searchby').change(function () {
        var selectedValue = $(this).val();
        if (selectedValue == 'date') {
            $('#searchcontent').attr('type', 'Date')
        }
        else {
            $('#searchcontent').attr('type', 'text')
        }
    })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>

<label for="searchby">Search By: </label>
    <select id="searchby"  name="search_by">
        <option value="date">Date</option>
        <option value="type" selected>Type</option>
    </select>
<label for="searchcontent">Search value:</label>
<input id="searchcontent" type="text" name="search_data">
<input type="submit" value="search">

</div>
```